# google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/: Invalid value for type: FLOAT is not a valid value

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using the following code (using python client bigquery library)

```
with open('train-schema.json','r') as f:
    column_names = json.load(f)['ColName']
for key in column_names.keys():
    dtype = column_names[key]
    schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(key,column_names[key],))
# 
table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
print(schema) #output below
print(
    "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
)
```

The schema list if fine

```
SchemaField('Sensor - 590', ' FLOAT64', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None), SchemaField('Output', 'INT', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)]
```

But the create_table code return

```
SchemaField('Sensor - 590', ' FLOAT64', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None), SchemaField('Output', 'INT', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)]
```

Tried this with FLOAT,FLOAT64,DECIMAL but doesnot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are facing is because of an additional space in value in  your JSON file. I tried with FLOAT64 and INT64 and both are working for me.

**Sample JSON file:**

{"a":"Float64"}

I ran the following code :

```
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
 
with open('train-schema.json','r') as f:
   client = bigquery.Client()
   table_id = "ProjectID.Dataset.Table"
   column_names = json.load(f)
   schema = []
for key in column_names.keys():
   dtype = column_names[key]
   schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(key,column_names[key],))
#
table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
print(schema) #output below
print(
   "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
)
```

It gave me the following output :

[image]